# How to use a windows laptop with broken keyboard and touchpad

Tags: windows-10, remote-access

I have an HP ZBook 17 laptop running Windows 10 that does not respond to input from the built-in keyboard, the built in touchpad, or any external keyboard or mouse I've tried. I am able to log in using the fingerprint reader, but once I do this the only way I can interact with the computer is with the power button. Not especially helpful.
Interestingly, I *am* able to use the escape key to access the boot menu, and within the boot menu the mouse and keyboard work fine. Once Windows starts up (even in safe mode) that functionality is gone.
If anyone has a possible solution, please let me know. However, my main question is this: how can I even begin to troubleshoot when the computer doesn't respond to anything I do? I was wondering if remote access might be an option, but I don't have any remote access software set up on the target computer. Thoughts?

Comment: @Moab as I said in the first sentence, the computer doesn't respond to input from _any_ keyboard or mouse that I have tried, whether built-in or external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the eventual solution to my problem (if it can be called a solution) was a complete reinstall of Windows. Even the built-in reset process failed to complete... my OS really was "hosed". However, since my original question was about how to work with a computer that doesn't have a working mouse or keyboard, here's some insight that might be helpful for future readers.
First of all, getting your computer to boot into the recovery environment gives you access to a command prompt. If you aren't used to using a command prompt, it might take some time and research to get things done, but you do have access to your whole file system and registry, meaning you can backup files and do some troubleshooting. There are several ways to get into recovery mode. Here's one that works using nothing but the power button. Turn on your computer and wait for the windows logo to appear onscreen, then immediately interrupt the boot process by pressing the power button again. Once the computer has shut down, repeat this process two more times. Then, turn on the computer, and it should boot into recovery mode.  Once you enter recovery mode, click **Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt**.
A few notes:

1. This command prompt runs from the X: drive, and things will look different from the command prompt in normal Windows. For example, I found my files from my normal OS living in a drive labeled D, even though I'm used to seeing that drive labeled C. Also, if you want to edit the registry for your normal system, you'll have to take some additional steps (see this link: https://adamtheautomator.com/offline-registry-editor/).
2. There are a lot of other potentially useful options in recovery mode, so explore a little.
3. If your windows installation is too screwed up to even access recovery mode, they you can also access it from a bootable windows USB without having to reinstall Windows (yet, although you're likely destined to do it eventually. See this link: https://windowsloop.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-recovery-mode/).

Once in the command prompt, it may be possible to gain remote access to your system from another computer using remote desktop. This is NOT something I have tried, but if you really want to try fixing your system instead of nuking it and starting over, I think it's worth a try. See this link for enabling remote desktop from the registry editor (again, note that the process is a little different in the recovery environment):
https://www.top-password.com/blog/enable-remote-desktop-with-registry-powershell-or-command-prompt/
and this link for using remote desktop:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c#ID0EDD=Windows_10
I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

For additional confirmation that your operating system is hosed (technical term), consider to boot to a Live CD of the OS of your choice. You will require another computer to create a bootable USB or optical disk, but if you are able to start, say, a Linux Live OS, and the input devices work, you can have confidence that the Windows system is in bad shape.

Your last option may be only to boot a Win 10 OS recovery, or if your machine has a recovery partition, to use that.

Comment: If none of the hypotheses above is doable then reinstall Windows.

Comment: Yes, that's the last paragraph.